# C++ STL: Why is there no upper_bound equivalent that retrieves the greatest element smaller then a specific key?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search-tree

Usually, STL is built for speed. However, there is only upper_bound and lower_bound on map and set data structures and no operation to retrieve the entry with the greatest key that is less than an input key `k`. Why is this? I know I can simply do an `lower_bound` and do a `--it` to retrieve this, but depending on the data structure it might be more efficient to search for the correct entry right away instead of searching for another one and then going back one step.

For example, `std::map` uses a Red-black tree, i.e. a binary search tree. If the element that is returned by `upper_bound` is the smallest element that is greater than the root, then `--it` must walk back to the root, enquiring O(log n) additional cost.

If this was Java, I would be fine with the design decision. However, STL is built for maximum speed, so why was this operation left out?

**Clarification:
I am not talking about `std::upper_bound` which can take another comparator but the methods of `std::map` and `std::set`.**

Comment: Do you mean "simply do a `lower_bound` and do a `--it`"?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I am aware of that. I wrote that in my second sentence. Please read the question properly :)

Comment: Ahem, please read it properly yourself. I read it, thanks. You wrote `upper_bound`, I'm asking it you mean `lower_bound` (and it's the fourth sentence not the second)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Lol, true, I didnt read your comment properly. Shame on me, sry :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, to obtain the greatest element that is less than the key, you would have to do:

```
auto it = m.lower_bound(k);
--it;
```

which means to find the first element that is not less than `k` and move back one element. If there was to be one function to do this, e.g., `auto it = m.last_less_element(k);`, then that function would have to be implemented in the *exact same way*, that is, find the first element not less than `k` and move back once. This is because there is no way to know that there isn't an element greater but still less than `k` unless you find the first element not less than `k`. So, there is no performance gain to have from having such a function, it would merely be a syntactic shortcut / convenience. And even then, the cost of moving back once is negligible in comparison to the cost of the look-up itself.

Second, if you wanted to iterate from the beginning to the last element less than the key, then you would do:

```
for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.lower_bound(k); ++it) { /* ... */ };
```

In other words, the way the `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` functions are made, they are idiomatic of standard iterator ranges, and that is very important. On that ground alone, it is justifiable to not include a special function like `last_less_element` as it would introduce a counter-idiomatic function in the interface of the `map` or `set` classes, and with no performance gain. So, it would cause pain, yet, no gain.

And as a final note, binary search trees (like a Red-black trees) are made for look-up operations mainly, with a marginal benefit of in-order traversals. They are not streamlined for in-order traversals, they shouldn't be used if that is the main operation you want to do. Ordered maps or sets are useful when the main operations are look-up operations, with an *occasional* need for an in-order traversal. Other alternatives should be considered in the reverse situation (e.g., sorted vectors, tree layouts *à la* von Emde Boas, etc.).

Comment: What a shame. I mistyped the whole question :(. I was looking for `last_element_not_greater` instead of `last_element_less`. In contrast to `last_element_less`, the other function DOES HAVE a more efficient solution than doing `upper_bound` + `--it`. Since there are so many answers for the old question here, I have created a new question for my problem: C++ STL: Why is there no upper_bound equivalent that retrieves the greatest element that is not greater than a specific key?

Answer (score 4):

Because you can do exactly what you want with `std::lower_bound` simply by inverting the predicate.

Comment: `std::map::lower_bound` doesn't take a predicate, though, and `std::lower_bound` on a map sucks.

Comment: @jrok: `lower_bound` does have an overload that takes a predicate.  And `std::upper_bound` on a map would be just as bad as `lower_bound` is, and that seems to be what the question is about (using `upper_bound` on containers without random access iterators). If you're using a container with random access iterators, then `--it` wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  OP doesn't talk about `std::lower_bound`, but [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) (at least that's how I understood the Q).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I think the point is about using the non-member versions from `<algorithm>` vs using the member functions.

Comment: of course, I am talking about the member functions of map and set. I know that the `std::lower_bound` function can take a predicate. I clarified my question.